# Get the entire list of table's and column's using single line Sql query.Is that possible?

Tags: sql

I have searched for this....but no solution. I want a single query which produces all table names and their column names..

Comment: Every platform is different. Is this for Oracle, SQL Server, MS Access? Note: SQL is not SQL Server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you what you want

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.name AS TableName,
    c.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id;
```